# Android: displaying image to ImageView using String as name of the image(in real device)

Tags: android

I cant load an image from `@drawable` to ImageView using String as name of the image.

Here's my code;

```
String uri = "@drawable/"+imgname;  // image file
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(uri , "drawable", getPackageName());
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resID); //<----line with error
            ImageView imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hardImg);
            imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

error log:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Comment: Remove `"@drawable/"`. You just need the resource name, which is the filename, without the extension.

Comment: I just did... but still having the same error.

Comment: does that image name exist in drawable folder?

Comment: yes. string names are from ext db and I already checked all case if it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `"@drawable/"`. That is what the second parameter to `getIdentifier` already does.

```
getResources().getIdentifier(imgname, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Will generate the integer resource ID for `<your package name>.R.drawable.<imgname>`, or `0` if that resource does not exist.

> Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)

Thus, your error message.

**Note** : Android resources can only contain certain characters.

Comment: okay. so, I made this `String uri = imgname;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(uri , "drawable", getPackageName());` but still having error.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame/com.example.hamira.wordmatchinggame.ingamehard}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Comment: Yes. Read the quote from the docs I provided. I have no idea what `imgname` is being set to, but obviously that name doesn't exist in your application's `res/drawable` folder

Comment: I tried to give a direct name like `imgname = "ac.png"`. ac.png is clearly exist in `res/drawable` but I still have the same error again :-(

Comment: I tried something else and it showed up! I dont understand.

Comment: Like I said it the other comment. You want `R.drawable.ac` **not** `R.drawable.ac.png`, so `imgname = "ac"`

Comment: the `imgname` got Ac name on db... I changed it awhile ago. but still getting 'Ac' not ac. so I 'clean' and 'rebuild' my project for the new db I editted. `imgname` containing "ac" is now matched to the image on `res/drawable`. Thank you @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
String uri = "@drawable/"+imgname;  // image file with extension, make sure image name is correct.
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(uri , null, getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resID); 
ImageView imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hardImg);
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: you mean something like this one?

`String uri = "@drawable/"+imgname+".png";`

Comment: @Jay No. Given the file `your_image.png` and you want `R.drawable.your_image`. Android doesn't really care you have a `png`, so `@drawable/your_image` is the resource

Comment: @cricket_007 I must not. `imgname` holds different image names on button click.. It change the image base on this string name. names are stored in external db.

Comment: @Jay You misunderstand my comment. `"@drawable/"+imgname+".png"` is not correct. That was all i said.

Comment: @cricket_007 my bad.